# Rename phylo tip labels with separate df

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

I am looking to rename 1290 tip labels in my phylo tree using a second df.  I am able to rename one label at a time using the below code:

```
phylo$tip.label[phylo$tip.label=="e54924083c02bd088c69537d02406eb8"] <- "something"
```

but this is clearly inefficient.  How may I rename all labels with a second df that contains the original tip labels and the new labels?  I can provide example data if necessary (the files are very large).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an example tree:

```r
oldTree <- ape::read.tree(text = "(t6, (t5, (t4, (t3, (t2, t1)))));")
old <- c("t1", "t3", "t6")
new <- c("tip_1", "tip_3", "tip_6")
plot(oldTree)
```

[image: Start tree]

A robust approach would be:

```
tree <- oldTree
tree$tip.label[match(old, tree$tip.label)] <- new
plot(tree)
```

[image]

Thomas's code will only work if the order of labels is identical in `tree$tip.label` and `old.labels`.

```r
tree <- oldTree
my_data_frame <- data.frame(old.labels = old,
                            new.labels = new)

## Find the old labels in the tree
tree$tip.label[tree$tip.label %in% my_data_frame$old.labels] <- my_data_frame$new.labels

plot(tree)
```

Here, tips have the wrong labels:
[image: Error]

Comment: Thank you MartinSmith and ThomasGuillerme.  I appreciate your time and knowledge!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the value matching function `%in%` to first detect which labels are in the "old labels" column in your data frame and then replace them by the "new labels".

```
## A random tree
my_tree <- rtree(20)

## A data.frame of names to replace
my_data_frame <- data.frame(old.labels = c("t1", "t3", "t9"),
                            new.labels = c("tip_1", "tip_3", "tip_9"))

## Find the old labels in the tree
my_tree$tip.label[my_tree$tip.label %in% my_data_frame$old.labels] <- my_data_frame$new.labels
```

`my_tree$tip.label %in% my_data_frame$old.labels` returns a logical vector (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) of each tips that matches the `my_data_frame$old.labels` which you can then easily replace by something of your choice of the same length (i.e. `length(which(my_tree$tip.label %in% my_data_frame$old.labels)) == length(my_data_frame$new.labels)`).

Comment: Hello Thomas! Thank you for your help.  I have confirmed that each tip matches both the old and new labels (using your code above) yet as I attempt to replace the matching tips using the new labels, the old labels remain.  My df to re-label: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/n41ceyhuhvepj33/asv_id.rds?dl=0>. My tree: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/elwitwegp88typx/tree.rds?dl=0>.